# php won't include an existing file: permission denied

Tags: php, windows, permissions, include

You will laugh if you read to the end of this :) This is now driving me nuts - can't get php to include an existing file with proper permissions set etc.

I have test.php file and "lib/tools.php" file.

I run the following code:

```
$fn = 'C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www\lib\tools.php';
if(file_exists($fn)){
    echo "Trying to INCLUDE THE BLoody file: $fn";
if(require_once($fn)==false) echo("failed to include: ".$fn);
}
```

and get the following:

> Trying to INCLUDE THE BLoody file:
>   C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www\lib\tools.php
>   Warning:
>   require_once(C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www):
>   failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in
>   C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www\test.php on
>   line 5 Fatal error: require_once():
>   Failed opening required ''
>   (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in
>   C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www\test.php on
>   line 5

Now, this is running Windows/IIS and recent version of php.

The following works fine if I call another php file from same with tools.php directory with the following code in it:

```
require('tools.php');
$mytools = new tools();
$mytools->ShowGallery();
```

This is driving me really mad :) IIS is setup to annon auth with app pool identity - I can see php-cgi.exe is running under Local Service account and I did make sure tools.php effective permissions allow full access for this account.

I enabled security auditing for this tools.php file for failed attempts and it's not showing any issues.

ok, I went ahead and installed ProcMon to see what's going on here. All I get is "FAST IO DISALLOWED" for "Query Open" operation. Mmmmm? Windows7 yeah.

I'm lost, please help :)

Comment: Could it be `require` vs. `require_once`? I'm not sure what exactly they return, but I could imagine that `require_once` returns `false` if the file was already included.

Comment: no, same result:

$fn = 'C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds\www\lib\tools.php';
if(file_exists($fn)){
 echo "Trying to INCLUDE THE BLoody file: $fn";
require($fn);
}

Comment: Yeah, deleted my answer. Looking at the error message it obviously did not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - got this sorted.

The issue in fact had nothing to do with permissions: had a error in tools class constructor and this was causing this. Why was php throwing this permission error - that's another question :)

Thanks, all!

Comment: Please answer your own question then so others with similar problems can benefit later.

Comment: undefined index in tools class constructor was causing this. Weird that I was getting fatal permission error instead of a non-fatal warning.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exact path the warning throws, it still looks like a permission problem with the www directory or the one below (ThreeDiamonds)

Could it be that `C:\Sasha\ThreeDiamonds` has a permission problem while the directories below do not? That would account for why it works with a relative path.

Comment: well, I have checked for Effective permissions - as longs as these are fine access will be provided.

In fact, the issue had nothing to do with permissions I will update my answer to explain the details.